# How to access wp_query in block pattern

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I want to create an advanced "next / previous post" block pattern (with title, feature image, etc. ) It' registered and shows up in the FullSiteEditor.

However I can't get the current post object / query. Probably because block patterns are registered at init. So the query is not available yet?! Any ideas how to solve this would be very appreciated.

Simplified Code is:

```php
$works_1 = get_template();
$works_4 = get_site_url();

global $post;
global $wp_query;

$works_not_1 = get_the_ID();
$works_not_2 = get_post($post);
$works_not_3 = $post->ID; // Throws ERROR
$works_not_4 = $wp_query->post->ID; // Throws ERROR
$works_not_5 = get_page_uri($post);
$works_not_5 = get_the_title();

return array(
    'title'         => __('das nächste projekt', 'tttstarter'),
    'categories'    => array('pages'),
    'content'       => '<!-- wp:paragraph --><p>' . esc_html($works_not_3) . '</p><!-- /wp:paragraph -->',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that needs a hack for this, I use this one:

```
$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$post_id = url_to_postid($url);
$post = get_post($post_id);
```

Comment: Looking forward to when this doesn't need a hack!

Comment: this probably works, but... ewwwwwwww